# GridSplitter not resizing content in grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, grid, gridsplitter

I have a `Grid` with 2 rows and 4 columns.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="144"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="136"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="290"/>
```

3rd column has a `GridSplitter`:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column ="3" Background="Gray"  ResizeDirection="Columns" 
              Grid.RowSpan="3"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Margin="7,-2,278,1"/>
```

After adding the splitter, it doesn't stretch to left or right. Is there some other implementation I need to do to to split and expand content in the grid?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix this

```
       <GridSplitter Grid.Column ="2" Background="Gray"  
       Width="5" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
         Margin="0,94,4,0" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
```